# How to accept k terms in a prolog rule?

Tags: prolog

I have this code:

```
stmt([pass|Tail], Tail) :- !.
stmt([use, X|Tail], Tail) :- atom(X),!.
stmt([declare, X|Tail], Tail) :- atom(X),!.

stmts(X, X) :- !.
stmts(X, Y) :- stmt(X, Z), stmts(Z, Y).

blck([begin, _, end|Tail], Tail) :- !.
```

My goal is that given a blck(List1, List2), this is true if List1 starts with atoms that match "begin <stmts> end" and then continues with the atoms in List2.

An example that would return true would be:

```
blck([begin,declare,x,use,x,end,tail],[tail]).
```

My current code for blck takes in an _ as a term. However, it only works for a single term, and I want it to accept k terms. Or better yet stmts(). I am at a complete loss as to how you can do k terms in the definition. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have a wildcard `_` stand for any number of variables. As already started with `stmts`, there needs to be some kind of recursion involved, but that also needs a proper recursion end or base case. `stmts` is a circular definition that always results in the same list. Instead, each step should consume a statement and the whole recursion must end on `end`.

In the following approach, blck starts with `begin`and passes over to a `body`, which then checks statements until either an `end` is found (results in `true`), or an empty list or a non-statement (results in `false`).

```
body([end|Tail], Tail).
body(Statements, Tail) :- stmt(Statements, T1), body(T1,Tail).

blck([begin|Body], Tail) :- body(Body, Tail).
```